# Программирование с использованием планшета WACOM в Windows на C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, api

Имеется планшет Wacom Cintiq 13HD. Мне необходимо написать программу на C# (WPF) с использованием этого планшета. Существует ли какое-либо API для использования функций планшета (обработка касаний) и где получить это API?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.wacom.com/

[development-kits-sdks](http://signature.wacom.eu/products/software/software-development-kits-sdks/)

[developer support page с примерами](http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/)

[похожый вопрос в англоязычном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383203/how-to-get-graphic-tablet-pen-pressure-value)